How do I disable the yellow banner warning after disabling Javascript in Acrobat Pro DC?

"JavaScript is currently disabled and this document uses it for some features Enabling JavaScript can lead to potential security issues"

This is the message I get after disabling Javascript via Registry. How do I completely get rid of such silly warnings?
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\JSPrefs] 
"bEnableJS"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\FeatureLockDown]
"bDisableJavaScript"=dword:00000001
"bDisableTrustedFolders"=dword:00000001
"bDisableOSTrustedSites"=dword:00000001
"bDisableTrustedSites"=dword:00000001


Edit the document and purge the JavaScript from the document. If you didn’t create the document that might be more difficult if the document actually requires it

I did not create the document. There are many docs that use javascript to give a popup, so I just disabled JS, but now the annoying yellow banner comes up - so I need a way to disable that banner too.

If there is actually JavaScript in the document you cannot
